# Bind SQL data with SharePoint Gridview

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql, spgridview

I'm developing a SharePoint solution, In an Application Page, I want to place `SPGridView` and I have to bind it with SQL server data.

Is it possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, here is a basic example:

> ```
> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     const string ConnectionString = @"Persist Security Info=False; Integrated Security=SSPI; Server=hercules\sqlexpress;Connect Timeout=30;Database=TestDB;";
>     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
>     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CustomerTable", con);
>     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>     adp.Fill(ds);
>
>    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
>     gridview1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
>     gridview1.DataBind();
>  }
> ```

from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2747c77a-a4da-4625-a56f-29c9e23b3071/how-to-display-a-backend-sql-server-table-in-spgridview-using-visual-studio?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Answer (score -1):

yes we can bind data to spgridview same as gridview.

Comment: Can you please add more details to this answer about how that is done? Your answer is not as helpful as it could be right now :)